# Combinatorics— Choosing a minimum of k objects — Ranking system problem

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

I have stumbled across an interesting exercise regarding combinatorics and am trying to figure out whether I have been interpreting it correctly. The base of the problem goes as follows: “A lecture visited by 300 students at a university has a total of 10 different exercises groups (from A to J) which can be ranked by each student from 0 to 5, with 0 being “least preferred” and 5 being “best choice” for the student. Each student hast to rank every exercise group (before he will be accepted into one).”

The first task was about in how many different/ unique variations the exercise groups can be ranked, which I found to be n^k (since there are no restrictions)

As for task b) I am a bit unsure about my reasoning, the task says “Since some students found a trick on how to get quicker into a specific exercise group, by ranking a total of nine of the exercise groups with 0 and the one they wanted to attend with 5, there has been a restriction of having to rank at least 3 of the exercise groups with a positive ranking. In how many different ways can a student now rank the lecture’s exercise groups?”

As far as my understanding went; I considered the ranking of 3,4,5 to be the positive ranks, meaning a student could for instance request a rank of $${0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 4 5} $$ or $$ {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5} $$ etc.

Meaning he would have to choose a minimum of $$\binom{10}{3}$$ but could potentially choose more positive ranks as well. As soon as he would’ve chosen a specific/the minimum amount of positively ranked lectures the “empty spaces” could be filled with any other rank and ordered amongst themselves by $$(10-k)! $$

So my answer would therefore be, in order to find the total of all possible solutions for ranking all exercise groups by matching a minimum requirement:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=3}^{10}\binom{10}{k} * (10-k)!$$

Is it correct? I would be looking for possible thinking errors and/or corrections on my answer and even further approaches to come to a solution; I find combinatorics to be very interesting but sometimes am getting definitions mixed up in  distinguishing particles of a problem. Any feedback would be of great help and further recommendations are greatly appreciated, thank you :) !

Answer (score 1):

Originally you had $6^{10}$ possibilities.  For similar reasons, if somebody gives positive scores (I feel "ranks" is the wrong word here) to $k$ exercise groups, you are going to have to multiply by $5^k$ for their possible scores (and by $1^{10-k}=1$ for those with $0$-score) in your later calculations.

Meanwhile I do not see why you have $ \times (10-k)!$.  Your ${10 \choose k}$ is the number of ways of of choosing which $k$ to have positive scores and which $10-k$ to have $0$-scores. They are already in order A,B,...,J.

So $$\sum\limits_{k=3}^{10} {10 \choose k} 5^k$$ which should be the same as $$6^{10}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^2 {10 \choose k} 5^k$$ if you simply subtract prohibited scores.

Comment: Thank you so so much for the thorough correction :) !! I think I went wrong with the (10-k)! because I assumed I would have to fill some sort of empty spaces with any different scores (similar to problems such as arranging 5 women among 3 men (meaning if I would’ve placed _ _ _ P P P _ _ _ _ (p for positive) I would still need to fill gaps)) but did not take into account the subtracting the total of prohibited scores. English is sadly not my first language so I’m also very grateful for the grammatical/ language correct!!